# Как сохранить структуру C# в строку JSON?

Tags: json, c#

Как сохранить структуру C# в строку JSON?

Comment: [Как сериализовать и десериализовать данные JSON.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/bb412179.aspx)

Comment: Советую посмотреть на [json.org](http://www.json.org/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Также постарайтесь не обойти стороной хорошую библиотеку [Newtonsoft.JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)

Тривиальный пример использования. Есть структура `UserInfo`:

```
struct UserInfo
{
    public string Name;
    public byte Age;
}
```

Сериализация может выглядеть так:

```
var data = new UserInfo {Name = "Ivan", Age = 42};

string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
```

На выходе имеем:

```
{
  "Name": "Ivan",
  "Age": 42
}
```

Можно переопределять имена полей в json:

```
struct UserInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("username")]
    public string Name;

    public byte Age;
}
```

Получим:

```
{
  "username": "Ivan",
  "Age": 42
}
```

И так далее. Библиотека очень мощная, читайте документацию.

Comment: Это практически стандарт на сегодня, да.